# How to destructure an array within an object and rename the variables created from it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I want to destructure the following object (simplified here):

```
export class Service = {
  ...
  details: {
    overview: [
      {
        title: {
          de: 'Mock Example',
          en: 'Mock Example',
        },
        description: {
          de: 'Lorem ipsum...',
          en: 'Lorem ipsum...',
        },
      },
      {
        title: {
          de: 'Mock Example 2',
          en: 'Mock Example 2',
        },
        description: {
          de: 'Lorem ipsum...',
          en: 'Lorem ipsum...',
        },
      },
    ],
    ...
```

I only want to have "service" on the right side and name the index 0 of the overview array "problem" and the index 1 of the overview array "solution" like this:

```
const { problem, solution } = service;
```

I've tried the following approach, but it doesn't work that way. And I don't quite understand how I can rename the variables to "problem" and "solution"?

```
  const { 
    details: { 
      overview[0]: { 
        ...
      }, 
    }, 
    details: {
      overview[1]: {
        ...
      }
    }
  } = service;
```

Comment: You can't use `service` alone on the right side and do what you're asking. You could do `const [ problem, solution ] = service.details.overview;`

Comment: AFAIK you can't rename on destructuring, and again, AFAIK, you can't destructure an object into an array or viceversa.

Comment: `const { details: { overview: [problem, solution] } } = service;` @EmilioGrisolía you can rename using destructuring `const { id: ident } = { id: 1 };` declares and assigns `obj.id` to `ident`

Comment: @pilchard Oh that's great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, that's what you're after:

```js
const service = {
    details: {
        overview: [{
                title: {
                    de: 'Mock Example',
                    en: 'Mock Example',
                },
                description: {
                    de: 'Lorem ipsum...',
                    en: 'Lorem ipsum...',
                },
            },
            {
                title: {
                    de: 'Mock Example 2',
                    en: 'Mock Example 2',
                },
                description: {
                    de: 'Lorem ipsum...',
                    en: 'Lorem ipsum...',
                },
            },
        ]
    }
}
 
const {details: {overview: [problem, solution]}} = service
      
console.log(problem, solution)
```